# How to create `EAAccessory` object without connecting to real bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I'm writing unit test case where the `EAAccessory` object is required in my testing module.

So I was tried creating `EAAccessory` object without connecting to real bluetooth device and `EAAccessoryManager`, But I was unable to assign `isConnected` and `serialNumber` to `EAAccessory` instance since those are readonly variables.

Hence I decided to mocking `EAAccessory` class and created `EAAccessoryMock` class by inheriting `EAAccessory` class and overriding `isConnected` and `serialNumber` variables to return my own values.

I thought everything was fine since there was no compiler error. But I received runtime error given below.

> caught "EAAccessoryInitException", "-init not supported. EAAccessoryManager is responsible for creating all objects."

So Can anyone please guide me to mock `EAAccessory` class OR if there is any other way to create `EAAccessory` object without mocking and without connecting to real bluetooth device?

Comment: Any luck? Please share your solution if you found one!

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately won't have much luck with creating your own instances of `EAAccessory` objects or subclassing the class. There is a better way of mocking though that won't require touching the `EAAccessory` class itself (well, almost).

The easiest way to do this would be to define a protocol that contains all of the `EAAccessory` values that you need, then define an empty extension to the `EAAccessory` class that conforms to the new protocol, like so:

```
protocol MyAccessory {
    var isConnected: Bool { get }
    var serialNumber: String { get }
}

extension EAAccessory: MyAccessory {}
```

Then, if you're listening for accessories using the `EAAccessoryDidConnect` notification, you can unwrap the value in the `userInfo` dictionary as your new protocol type instead of `EAAccessory`:

```
let myAccessoryObject = notification.userInfo?[EAAccessoryKey] as? MyAccessory
```

---

For testing and mocking the accessory, now all you need to do is create a new class or struct that conforms to the `MyAccessory` protocol instead of the `EAAccessory` class:

```
struct MockAccessory: MyAccessory {
    let name: String
    let protocolStrings: [String]
}

func testSendingNotifications() {
    let userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any] = [
        EAAccessoryKey: MockAccessory(isConnected: true, serialNumber: "cocoa-puffs")
    ]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name.EAAccessoryDidConnect,
                                    object: nil,
                                    userInfo: userInfo)
}
```